# Negative of "shall"

Tags: negation

I really wonder if there is a negative of *shall*. I've heard something like *shan't*. For example *I shan't* or *Shall we go to the cinema? No, I shan't*. I don't know whether this usage is correct or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "true" exactly? It's been a perfectly acceptable contraction since the mid 1600's.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shan't

Comment: Voting to reopen. In normal parlance, the negative response to *"Shall we go to the cinema?"* is definitely not *"No, we shan't"*. It's not at all the same as, for example, *"Will we get front-row seats?"*, where *"No, we won't"* would be a perfectly standard response. OP is asking about something which I consider to be primarily idiomatic usage, which the only answer here so far doesn't address at all - it just says that (IMHO, for more literal contexts) *"shall"* is in decline.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is asking about the contracted negative  of _shall_; he is not asking about when to use _shall_, and _will_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I don't read it like that at all. The question title, and the first sentence of the text, ask for the negative of "shall". Just because he mentions that he's heard *"shan't"* doesn't change that. I myself only mentioned *"will"* because in normal parlance the negative response to that verb is just bog-standard *"won't"* or *"will not"*, whereas it doesn't work like that in the case of "idiomatic" questions starting with *"Shall we/I..."*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I really wonder there is a negative of _shall_." I think that explains itself. If somebody has a doubt about when using _will_, or _shall_, he asks a different question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: To repeat myself - my mentioning *"will"* at all was simply an aside to flag up that in this idiomatic usage of *"Shall we...?"*, our standard "negative response" doesn't involve negating the verb used in the original question. We would do that if the original verb was *"Will we..."*, but with *"Shall we..."* the negative is more likely to switch verbs - for example, *"Let's not"*. To repeat myself even more, I still think the question shouldn't have been closed, and I don't think you are seriously considering my reasoning here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The user is not asking when _shall not_ is used; it is asking if the contracted negative form of _shall_ exists. Your interpretation sounds like saying that who asks "What time is it?" is asking about timezones.

Comment: I don't wish to be insulting, but you are simply repeating yourself, throwing in random irrelevancies, and ignoring the point I'm making. Let's leave it to see if four others will agree with my position and vote to reopen, since I'm obviously not getting through to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative of *shall* is *shall not*. All modal verbs have contracted negative forms, and the contracted negative form of *shall not* is *shan't*. *Shall* and its negative both seem to be in decline and their use is limited to mainly to legal contexts and the expression of politeness in some questions.

Comment: Not all modals, *may* doesn't.

Comment: It does, *mayn't*, although it's rarely used. Here is an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shan+%27+t%2Cshouldn+%27+t%2Cmayn+%27+t&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) for the three least used modals. *Shan't* and *mayn't* both seem to be slowly becoming obsolete.

Comment: The OED has 24 citations that include ‘mayn’t’, most of them, admittedly, from before the twentieth century. There is, however, this from 1971: ‘It mayn't be too bad an idea.’

Comment: Also [mightn't](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mightn+%27+t%2Cmayn+%27+t&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which even though it's a bit more of a tongue-twister, seems to be clinging on much more than *"mayn't"*.